# Add "header" or library file to angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-controller

In C programs, it is easy to add a header file containing a set of library functions.

```
#include "ownlib.h";
```

In node.js, it is just as easy.

```
require('./ownlib.js');
```

I am trying to do the same for a AngularJS controller but there seems no easy to do it. What I do now is to add functions like those below at the bottom of my Angularjs controller `controllers.js`. Unfortunately, this make the controller file grow huge over time.

```
function convertXXXToJson(obj) {
    ... 
    return output;
}

function convertYYYToJson(obj) {
    ... 
    return output;
}
```

How to conveniently add an external library file to an angularjs controller?

It will be a nightmare if I have to create a module and do dependency injectancy for each external library file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the new functions in a separate file or multiple files and include them through script tag in your html file and you are done.

```
<script href="controllers-part1.js"></script>
<script href="controllers-part2.js"></script>
```

Now coming to the order in which you need to include the script tags in your html file. The order matters if you are executing something in your `controllers.js` immediately, and it uses some functions defined in `controllers-part<x>.js`. Then in that you need to include `controller-part<x>.js` files before `controllers.js`. Otherwise you can include them in any order.